# Cannot mount volume with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run up a docker container with a mounted local volume using docker-compose. In failure to get it working, I have reduced by docker-compose down to the most basic version:

```
version: '2'

services:
  php:
    image: php:5.6-apache
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
```

Upon doing this the mount appears in docker inspect:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/clark/Projects/apis/contracts",
                "Destination": "/var/www/html",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
```

But /var/www/html directory on the container is empty.

I have tried every combination I can think of. Absolute paths, relative paths, ${pwd}, named volumes, mounting to a directory that exists, mounting to a directory that doesn't exist... It's driving me crazy.

PLEASE can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: Your compose file is perfectly valid and should work. Please update question on how you're checking that directory in the container is empty - maybe the problem is there (FS permissions). Also suggest to mention the OS (whenever you're on GNU/Linux or macOS, or, possibly, Windows' WSL - this also matters). The answer below with a `command: ls -la /var/www/html` is a good idea, and if this is something really weird, a `command: cat /proc/mounts` (or `docker-compose exec php cat /proc/mounts` while the container's up) can also provide some potentially useful diagnostics.

Comment: Have the same issue and still not clear how to resolve it...

Answer (score 3):

Works here, the only difference is a version 3 docker-compose file.

```
mkdir /tmp/compose-test && cd /tmp/compose-test
touch iam_a_file
```

Docker compose file :

```
---
version: '3'

services:
  test:
    image: busybox
    command: ls -la /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
```

Ensure config is ok :

```
docker-compose config
```

Up all the stuff

```
docker-compose up
Creating composetest_test_1
Attaching to composetest_test_1
test_1  | total 8
test_1  | drwxr-xr-x    2 1000     users           80 Apr 26 16:47 .
test_1  | drwxr-xr-x    1 www-data www-data      4096 Apr 26 16:49 ..
test_1  | -rw-r--r--    1 1000     users          126 Apr 26 16:48 docker-compose.yml
test_1  | -rw-r--r--    1 1000     users            0 Apr 26 16:46 iam_a_file
```

Inspect show that when you provide a relative path, docker change it to a full path.

Edit: i also tried with php:5.6-apache, it works.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Okay so weird thing, when I try with your `ls -la /var/www/html`, that shows the directory full, like I would expect! But I'm going into the system using `docker -it run <name> /bin/bash` and the directory is empty when I do that. Browsing to the container's apache server also shows that the directory is empty.

Comment: Docker run create a new container and you dont provide any -v flag. Try the docker exec command.

Comment: Right! Haha I wondered that while I was typing that actually. Okay `docker-compose exec ls /var/html/www` shows what I expect. However, the apache listing still shows empty.. Also, not sure if it's related, but my containers don't have any IP address. Any reason that would be?

Comment: Maybe related to apache config not allowing directory listing but i'm not an apache expert 

Comment: It could be related to filesystem permissions, if Apache runs as non-root in the container. Run `docker-compose exec php /bin/bash` and then `ps aux` to see which user Apache runs as. If it's not `root` but, e.g., `www-data` - this could be the cause (check `ls -lad /var/www/html` output to see the actual *directory* permissions to determite whenever Apache can list its contents).